# Linker issue with header file

Tags: c, xcode, linker

In a C application I have a `main.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    foo f;
    bar b;
    return 0;
}
```

A `foo.h` (and `foo.c` file):

```
#ifndef foo_h
#define foo_h
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bar.h"
#include "utility.h"
typedef struct foo foo;
typedef struct bar bar;
struct foo {
    bar * b;
    int a;
};
#endif
```

A `bar.h` (and `bar.c` file):

```
#ifndef bar_h
#define bar_h
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
typedef struct foo foo;
typedef struct bar bar;
struct bar {
    foo * f;
    int a;
};
int get_b_a(bar b);
#endif
```

And a `utility.h` (with NO `utility.c`):

```
#ifndef utility_h
#define utility_h
int add(int a, int b);
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
#endif
```

This program will however not build in xcode as it complains about a linker problem:
`Duplicate symbol _add in bar.o and main.o`

I know I could easily solve this problem by creating a separate `utility.c` file, however I would rather not as it would cause too many files in a larger project.

What is best-practice to solve the above problem?

Comment: and that is why we use source files,not all-header code...

Comment: @SouravGhosh I know, but it is not always convenient, e.g. building an API in one header file.

Comment: If you use a language, you have to follow its conventions. There are things to be creative - this is not one of them. Why and how to use headers is explained in every C book.

Comment: @Olaf What would the convention be in this case? Create `utility.c`? I am asking because I thought there might be another approach?

Comment: Sorry, stack overflow is not a tutorial site. I'm afraid you really have to read a book. YOu need to get the whole picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is you have too many includes

you don'tneed to

```
#include "bar.h"
```

in foo.h because you include it in your main.c

what happens is the prepocessor will combine everything before the program is compiled...

... so what is happening is one copy of foo.h and bar.h is loaded into main and then inside foo.h and bar.h they reload bar.h and foo.h

so remove the

```
#include "bar.h"
```

from foo.h

and remove the

```
#include "foo.h"
```

from bar.h

It also looks as if you have too many definitions of the type

```
typedef struct foo foo;
```

this should only be in the entire code once.

edit after comments....

You could have a hierachy by in main.c

```
#include "foo.h"
```

and don't include "bar.h"

Then in foo.h you can have

```
#include "bar.h"
```

and then you will have only one copy of foo.h and bar.h in your program. (In bar.h you don't want to have any #includes)

Comment: But then it will not be "portable", in another application I might wish to only include "foo.h" in main as only `foo` is used directly?

Comment: @sigvardsen - Well then if you only wish to inlcude "foo.h" do you need "bar.h" to be in "foo.h"? If foo.h and bar.h do separate things then you can separate them, but if you need both to work together then it may be best to combine them

Comment: The point is that they can not be separate, I have also considered combining them. However one might think of a program where you only want to directly deal with foo, thus only include this in the main file, and leave the bar to be handled by other functions.

Comment: @sigvardsen - ok - so then you should #include "foo.h" in main and #include "bar.h" in foo and not in main - then you will only have one copy of foo.h and one copy of bar.h - i will edit answer....

Comment: I know, but the point is that I would then have to change foo and bar depending on the implementation. I think I'm going to go with a .c file for utility. Thank you for your answer!